# Erro HTTPS node JS_

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing

All my requests using my https tools, but ta giving file reading error. If I have already had the error and solved you can pass as resolved? I gave `chmod -R 777` permission to the directory but it still keeps giving me an error.

Follow test:

```
app.js 

var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

//Local de arquivos ssl
var server_key = './home/admin/conf/web/ssl.chat';
var server_crt =./'home/admin/conf/web/ssl.chat.crt';
var server_pen ='./home/admin/conf/web/ssl.chat.pen';

var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync(server_key),
cert: fs.readFileSync(server_crt),
ca: fs.readFileSync(server_pen),
};
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
console.log(new Date()+' '+
req.connection.remoteAddress+' '+
req.method+' '+req.url);
res.writeHead(200);
res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(4433);
--------------------Erro---------------------------------

$ node app.js
nternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/admin/web/chat/public_html/o'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This is an English speaking site, so please re-phrase your question in English.

Comment: Is this being run from within an nginx session? If so, that process probably doesn't have access to "/home" because of they way web server process security works.

Comment: I discovered the problem, it was not the path of the file but the name of the file that was with special characters.

Comment: Hey, please answer your question if you fixed the problem you found, or simply delete it if it's not worth answering, thanks!

Comment: Yes im use nginx in nginx load balance apache

Comment: Hello friends, I was able to solve with a configuration on the routes. In my case, you have to create a separate route so that the socket can communicate correctly.   https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/loadbalancing/use-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancer/?fbclid=IwAR3qq-mhqI0AyivaHfL__eSkUgaWhOfvd4ujndBfA7JJFaRIPvyM3ZKnI0o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve with a configuration on the routes. In my case, you have to create a separate route so that the socket can communicate correctly.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/loadbalancing/use-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancer/?fbclid=IwAR3qq-mhqI0AyivaHfL__eSkUgaWhOfvd4ujndBfA7JJFaRIPvyM3ZKnI0o